# Tablename with spaces at JDBC connection gives error

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, aws-glue

I'm trying to establish a connection in AWS Glue, using a pyspark script.
The JDBC connection is pointing to a Microsoft SQL Server in Azure Cloud.

When I try to enter the connection string, it works until it gets to the table that it should read. That's mainly because of the whitespace inside the table name. Do you have any hint on how to write the syntax here?

```
source_df = sparksession.read.format("jdbc").option("url","jdbc:sqlserver://00.000.00.00:1433;databaseName=Sample").option("dbtable", "dbo.122 SampleCompany DE$Contract Header").option("user", "sampleuser").option("password", "sampL3p4ssw0rd").load()
```

When you execute this, it always throws the error:

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o69.load. : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '.122'

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: add backticks? `"\`dbo.122 SampleCompany DE$Contract Header\`"`

Comment: @mck Backticks are MySQL specific, and even if that works, you would need to leave `dbo.` out of it. Given this is SQL Server, the OP should try `"dbo.[122 SampleCompany DE$Contract Header]"` or `"dbo.\"122 SampleCompany DE$Contract Header\""`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - your solution with the brackets around the table name worked!!!
"dbo.[122 SampleCompany DE$Contract Header]"

Thank you so much!

Comment: @Hawtin Good to hear, I also posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the presence of spaces (and probably the dollar sign, and the fact the identifier starts with numbers), you need to quote the object name. Quoting object names in SQL Server is done by enclosing it in brackets (or, though this may depend on the session config, double quotes).

Keep in mind that `dbo` is the schema, while `122 SampleCompany DE$Contract Header` is the table name. Schema and table name need to be quoted separately, not as a unit.

So, try to pass `"dbo.[122 SampleCompany DE$Contract Header]"`